# Can we use http:// schemes instead of https:// in WebAuthenticationBroker class during AuthenticateAsync( )

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I'm having a problem during the authentication process in my Windows Store application.  I am using the `WebAuthenticationBroker` class for authentication.  I have a URL with http:// schemes but `WebAuthenticationBroker` class doesn't allow to proceed while using `AuthenticateAsync()`.

Exception message is: `Only https:// schemes are allowed`.

So how can I solve this issue and authenticate with http:// schemes through `WebAuthenticationBroker` class.

For example:

```
var signInUrl = new Uri("http://example.com");

var WebAuthenticationResult = 
      await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(  
           WebAuthenticationOptions.None, 
           signInUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use http for a sign on.  This is by design.  Http is not secure, and to log on you are passing username and password.  Ergo, you must use https.

From the [Microsoft Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj856911.aspx):

> The first URL that an application will use to communicate with the online provider is required to be HTTPS.